# Dealing with brute force on RHEL

Tags: iptables, redhat, brute-force-attacks

Box got slow and decided to `vim /var/log/secure` and saw a bunch of brute force methods trying to ssh with names starting from A-Z.

`iptables` was installed so I added the ip via:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -s [ip] -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -s [ip] -j DROP
```

It seemed like it blocked his ip automatically. I did:

```
iptables -nvL|less
```

Which showed his IP being supposedly blocked:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 26G packets, 9985G bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
   23  1400 DROP       all  --  *      *       [HIS_IP]         0.0.0.0/0           
  26G 9985G PORTSEN    all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

Is this it? Do I need to use any command to actually save it? like `service iptables save`? Or is this automatically saved?

As a preventative measure, I'm going to follow a guide and add:

```
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name DEFAULT --rsource
iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -m recent --update --seconds 180 --hitcount 4 --name DEFAULT --rsource -j DROP
```

Are these measures enough for the low to medium level attacks? Would appreciate any input.

Comment: Only 23 packets? Is the box at normal speed now? Usually those attacks come from dynamic ip addresses, tomorrow he will be back.

Comment: Try denyhosts which check multiple retries in the secure log and block any ip with too many retries in a short time

Comment: @ott - there have been no entries/attempts since I applied it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather use a tool like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/) which automatically responds to brute force attacks and manages the IP bans.

Comment: So `fail2ban` would be a replacement over `iptables`, right? They can't live together, due to conflicts, etc..

Comment: @meder No, fail2ban will use iptables to block detected IPs. They can be used together.

Comment: I see. So with my current rules as is, after installing fail2ban, what basic configuration commands should I set, or will it auto-read the iptables and just configure automatically?

Comment: @meder Have a look at the [manual](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/MANUAL_0_8).

Answer (score 1):

Try with [denyhosts](http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/), it's in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

> DenyHosts is a script intended to be run by Linux system administrators to help thwart SSH server attacks (also known as dictionary based attacks and brute force attacks).

Comment: I suggest you use something that is maintained for you in an official (of sorts) repository instead of self-build stuff. The work needed to keep up with new versions, possible incompatibilities when something else is updated, and so on, just isn't worth it.